# Communication threads are blocked on Android 6.0.1 lenovo tablet 10" using javafxports

Tags: android, javafx, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I have built a video streaming application using Javafxports. App works on my mobile device huwaei p-smart Android 8 but fails to connect and load on Android 6 (Lenovo tab 10"). The application needs to discover the control module, connect to it and should receive data defined in FSGuiCommunications class (below).

```
01-17 11:58:30.326 23694 23723 I System.out: Discovering control module in the network1
    01-17 11:58:30.328 23694 23723 I System.out: im here1java.net.MulticastSocket@6ba742e
    01-17 11:58:30.328 23694 23723 I System.out: im here2/230.0.0.2
    01-17 11:58:30.328 23694 23723 I System.out: im here3
    01-17 11:58:30.329 23694 23723 I System.out: im here4java.net.DatagramPacket@65dabcf
    01-17 11:58:30.329 23694 23723 I System.out: im here5
    01-17 11:58:30.335 23694 23720 I System.out: FSGuiCommunications done
    01-17 11:58:31.435 23694 23720 W System.err: Loading FontFactory com.sun.javafx.font.freetype.FTFactory
    01-17 11:58:31.435 23694 23720 W System.err: Subpixel: enabled
    01-17 11:58:31.488 23694 23720 W System.err: Freetype2 Loaded (version 2.5.0)
    01-17 11:58:31.488 23694 23720 W System.err: LCD support Enabled
    01-17 11:58:31.892  2612  2612 D wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
    01-17 11:58:31.905  2612  2612 D wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: global_ctrl_sock-sendto: sock=11 sndbuf=163840 outq=0 send_len=48
    01-17 11:58:32.689 23694 23720 W art     : Before Android 4.1, method double javafx.scene.text.TextFlow.computeChildPrefAreaHeight(javafx.scene.Node, javafx.geometry.Insets) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in javafx.scene.layout.Region
    01-17 11:58:32.689 23694 23720 W art     : Before Android 4.1, method double javafx.scene.text.TextFlow.computeChildPrefAreaWidth(javafx.scene.Node, javafx.geometry.Insets) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in javafx.scene.layout.Region
    01-17 11:58:32.793 23694 23720 W art     : Before Android 4.1, method void com.sun.javafx.scene.transform.TransformUtils$ImmutableTransform.ensureCanTransform2DPoint() would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in javafx.scene.transform.Transform
    01-17 11:58:32.904 23694 23720 I System.out: loading done
    01-17 11:58:33.523 23694 23718 I System.out: max rectangle texture cell size = 62
    01-17 11:58:33.552 23694 23718 I System.out: wrap rectangle texture = 2 x 2
    01-17 11:58:33.558 23694 23718 I System.out: ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: AlphaTexture_Color.frag
    01-17 11:58:33.582 23694 23718 I System.out: ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: AlphaTextureDifference_Color.frag
    01-17 11:58:33.597 23694 23718 I System.out: ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Texture_Color.frag
    01-17 11:58:33.625 23694 23718 I System.out: ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: FillRoundRect_Color.frag
    01-17 11:58:33.639 23694 23718 I System.out: ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureRGB.frag
    01-17 11:58:33.655 23694 23718 I System.out: ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: DrawRoundRect_Color.frag
```

This is `logcat` generated output for Android 6.0.1.

```
public class FSGuiCommunications extends Thread {

    protected MulticastSocket socket = null;
    protected byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    static FSReceiverCM            m_cReceiverCM   = null;
    int intSenderPort                   = 6265;
    boolean m_bThreadRunning            = false;
    static boolean preLoaderDiscoveryThread=false; 
    static boolean preLoaderImgThread=false;
    static boolean setStageFlag=false;
    static Bitmap currentBitmap;

    /* 
     *  Discovering control module in the network
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Discovering control module in the network1");
            socket = new MulticastSocket(4444);
            System.out.println("im here1"+socket);
            InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.2");
            System.out.println("im here2"+group);
            socket.joinGroup(group);
            System.out.println("im here3");
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            System.out.println("im here4"+packet);
            try {
                System.out.println("im here5");
                socket.receive(packet);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            System.out.println("im here5 again");
            String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
            System.out.println("im here6"+received);
            InetAddress addr = packet.getAddress();

            System.out.println("Discovering control module in the network2");
            if(addr != null) {
                System.out.println("Response from: " + addr);
                System.out.println("received: "+received);
                preLoaderDiscoveryThread=true;
                startServers(addr);
                //                  System.out.println(preLoader_testThread);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Not connected to Control Module");
            }
            System.out.println(preLoaderDiscoveryThread);
            socket.leaveGroup(group);
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Receive image data from control module
     */

    private void startServers(InetAddress address) throws IOException
    {
        try {
            InetAddress local_ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            int port = 6562;
            System.out.println("startServers");
            InetSocketAddress socketAdress = new InetSocketAddress(local_ip, port);
            m_cReceiverCM = new FSReceiverCM(socketAdress);
            InetSocketAddress GUItoCM = new InetSocketAddress(address, intSenderPort);
            m_cReceiverCM.addClientToCM(GUItoCM);   
            m_cReceiverCM.sendMessageToControlModul("getMCState");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


        String groupID = "233.3.3.2";
        int groupPort = 5555;        
        MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(groupPort);
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(groupID);
        socket.joinGroup(group);
        boolean connected = socket.isConnected();

        //      if(connected)
        //          GUIMotionComposer.panMusical.setVisible(false);

        Thread m_cConnectionThread = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {                   
                byte[] buffer = new byte[600000];
                m_bThreadRunning = true;                
                while (m_bThreadRunning == true) {
                    try {
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                        socket.receive(packet);                     
                        int iSizeMsg = packet.getLength();
                        System.out.println("@m_cConnectionThread"+packet);
                        preLoaderImgThread=true;
//                      if(iSizeMsg > 0 && getStageFlag()==true)
                        if(iSizeMsg > 0)
                        {
                            Mat frame = new Mat();
                            buffer = packet.getData();
                            frame = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(buffer), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
                            System.out.println(buffer);System.out.println(frame.channels());System.out.println(frame.size());System.out.println(frame);

//                          Image imageToShow = Utils.mat2Image(frame);

                            Image imageToShow = Utils.convertMatToImage(frame);
                            try {
                                FSMainController.cVideoView.setImage(imageToShow);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println(e);
                            }


//                          Utils.onFXThread(mainGui.maincontroller.getImageView().imageProperty(), imageToShow);

                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        m_bThreadRunning = false;
                    }
                }   
            }
        };
        m_cConnectionThread.start();        

    }
```

From logcat I have observed that control hasn't went to startservers() block or even failed to receive packet. Does warning with Android 4.1 in logcat has to do anything with blocking the threads? I haven't observed this behavior on my mobile device Android 8.

Samsung Android 8.0.1

```
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288): Process: org.fxgui, PID: 18288
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "56.0dip"
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getFloat(TypedArray.java:416)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.<init>(ThreadedRenderer.java:408)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.create(ThreadedRenderer.java:304)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enableHardwareAcceleration(ViewRootImpl.java:1259)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:904)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:384)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:101)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3899)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3065)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
01-17 13:24:28.756: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Use `try {} catch (Throwable e) { System.out.println("Error"); e.printStackTrace(); }` and try again, see if your logcat provides more information.

Comment: @JoséPereda I haven't observed any stacktrace messages. control simply ignores the line. I have installed App on another tablet Android 8.0.1 from samsung but here App crashes on start. I have included the logcat output above

Comment: @JoséPereda how to define or provide App permissions for Android 6 to access WI-FI ?

Comment: Edit the AndroidManifest file of your project and add the missing permission. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078747/permission-for-accessing-wifi-in-android-6)

Comment: @JoséPereda adding this line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` to AndroidManifest.xml worked on Samsung tablet Android 8.0.1, which previously failed to start the App. But still not able to make it work on Android 6 tablet